# Facet_count not working using Whoosh backend

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I am not getting whoosh `facet_counts` to work with Haystack in my Django project:
`Python==2.7.8`, `Whoosh==2.7`, `Haystack==2.3.1`.

I received the error `"Warning: Whoosh does not handle faceting"` when I run the following:

```
In [1]: from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
In [2]: sqs = SearchQuerySet().facet('title')
In [3]: sqs.facet_counts() 

/Users/chriswedgwood/virtualenvs/omexchange/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/haystack/backends/init.py:35: Warning: Whoosh does not handle 
faceting. 

Out[3]: {}
```

In my `search_indexes.py`, I have declared:

```
title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title',faceted=True)
```

I thought I would change my backend to elastic search and see what happens
and I got results back:

```
In [1]: from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
In [2]: sqs = SearchQuerySet().facet('title')
In [3]: sqs.facet_counts() 

Out[3]: {u'dates': {}, u'fields': {'title': [(u'Event vlugkppylj', 2),
(u'Event jlomvcpidn', 2), (u'Event ryusgjejgg', 1), (u'Event pjetthkihw', 1),
(u'Event jdeestsxpb', 1), (u'Event hkmuyhnzjv', 1), (u'Event ewnxnvisdj', 1), 
(u'Chris event', 1)]}, u'queries': {}}
```

I'm a bit confused with the combination of the Haystack documents and the whoosh documents.

Do I need to define a schema in order to get the faceting to function? Where should I do that? In `search_indexes.py`?

Comment: This is an issue with Django-Haystack as whoosh does support faceting

Comment: issue #815 of Haystack https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/815